Trigger configuration changes manually in java Android
I have a scenario in my app where the expected behavior occurs during a device configuration change, such as an orientation change. This means that whenever the user changes the device's orientation, the app's configuration reloads.
Now, I would like to trigger this behavior manually in Java. How can I achieve this in a click listener?

What is "this behavior", specifically?

I have some custom views, which are stored in app storage, If I remove them programmatically and configuration changes, those widgets are restored. I don't have control over those views, as users can add or remove them like widgets. But I want to restore them in a certain case.

You can call recreate() or change the orientation programmatically using setRequestedOrientation().
